# Facebook ios SDK acting weird

Tags: ios, facebook

I i was using Facebook SDK for iOS v4.4 before. if Facebook was installed then it tried to get permission from the App and if not get will try to go to Facebook webpage using the browser. I have upgraded the device to ios 9 and changed  Facebook SDK for iOS v4.4  to  Facebook SDK for iOS v4.6. Right now it only try to get the permission from the browser even if the Facebook app is installed and open....

Is this a bug ?

i want it to try to ask permission from the Facebook app

Comment: Facebook iOS 9 have something different document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 please check. May you get help from it.

Comment: Thanks i will check it out and see..